# Does a sequence with convergent monotonic subsequences converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers.
Suppose we have two subsequences $\{x_{n_k}\}$ and $\{x_{m_j}\}$ that both converge to some $x$, and are monotonically increasing and decreasing respectively.

Does $\{x_n\}$ also converge to $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major hint: $$\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2},100,\frac{1}{3},\frac{-1}{3},100,\frac{1}{4},\frac{-1}{4},100,\ldots$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Aniket, on the contrary this provides an almost-complete answer to the question.  A bit of thought is required to fill in the blanks.  I've added a bit to help clarify.

Comment: @Aniket to be fair, the answer is as complete as the question - so it is definitely consistent

Comment: The question is too complete to deserve an answer ... isn't it? You can surely avoid answering such questions where there is no effort by the OP. There are plenty of questions out there...:-)

Comment: @aniket, in my opinion the question is perfectly well stated and reasonable.  Thank you for your suggestions about which questions I should answer, I will take them under advisement.